# HTML: Scalable Text

Tags: css, html, text, scaling

Hello I am making a website and i feel it is quite important that the text on the page is scalable for if the user has a smaller monitor or is using split screen.

I have the following HTML coding, that I believed would make it scale effectively but nothing happens?

HTML:

```
        <p id="text">
            View <a id="advertlinks" href="Prices.html">Prices</a> </br>Or <br><a id="advertlinks" href="Contact_Us.html">Book</a> A Lesson
        </p>
```

CSS

```
#text
{
z-index:100;
position:absolute;    
margin-top:-22%;
margin-left: 70%;
padding: 2%;
width: 22%;
height: 25%;
background-color: #f6da30;
opacity:0.6;
font-family: Impact, Charcoal, San-Serif;
font-size: 170%;
text-align: center;
-moz-border-radius: 30px;
border-radius: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Define “scalable”. If you mean the font size should depend on the dimensions of the display device, check old questions on that topic.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS media queries:

```
@media all {
    #text {
        /* Default font size */
        font-size: 12pt;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    #text {
        /* Font size for smaller displays/screens */
        font-size: 16pt;
    }
}
```

Further reading: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: Are media queries easy to implement, i've never used them before

Comment: they're about as easy as reading the link and copy pasting + modifying the parts you need...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text to scale relative to the screen width, then your best bet is a responsive text jQuery plugin such as [FlowType](http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/) and [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/). If you want something light-weight, then you can use my Scalable Text jQuery plugin:

http://thdoan.github.io/scalable-text/

Sample usage:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#text').scaleText();
}
</script>
```